# Queries on one channel multiple chaincode setup

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

1) In a channel with multiple chaincodes (say myccA and myccB) instantiated, when we query through myccB, do we also retrieve data/transactions that was posted through myccA?

2) Can we add a function inside myccB which will call one of the functions of myccA and then query the data?

3) What is rationale behind creating a Channel if querying from two different chaincodes gives different data/transactions?

4) If there are 3 orgs on a channel - say A, B and C. Org A and B have chaincode_1 installed and instantiated. Org B and C have chaincode_2 installed and instantiated. Can Org A (somehow) query data/transactions posted through chaincode_2? I'm asking this question because I believe the ledger is same on all Orgs of a channel.

Answer (score 2):

I differ with @gustavo only in the 2nd  Question you can invoke and query other chaincode data in the same channel if your peer has both chaincodes installed by calling mycca chaincode function:https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/developapps/chaincodenamespace.html#cross-chaincode-access

Answer (score 1):

1) No, each chaincode will have its own ledger, so the data in one won't be reached by the other one.

2) I don't think so. And it does not makes sense given the reason why channels exist.

3) Channels are used when the transactions between some organizations shouldn't be accessed by others. You should read more on the docs: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/channels.html.

4) Same as the first point, each chaincode has its own ledger.

This doc explains about channels and multiple chaincodes: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/network/network.html

Comment: I understand that a Channel is "a private “subnet” of communication between two or more specific network members, for the purpose of conducting private and confidential transactions". So, isn't it enough to have a Channel-wise segregation of ledger. Why do we have chaincode-level segregation of ledger? Why can't a transaction posted by one chaincode on a channel be accessed by another chaincode on the same channel? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a invoke chaincode function within another.
The following will do the trick

```
let chainCodeArgs = ["foo", data]; 
let response = await stub.invokeChaincode("chaincodeName", chainCodeArgs, "channelName");
```

You can call function foo (which is a function in chaincode to be called ) wherein you can access the data of that particular chaincode.
It's obvious that if you are executing a function which is part of myccA it'll fetch all data ( or however you write the code to fetch data ) related to that CC, so now if you call the function of myccA from myccB ( as i have metioned above) you will see data written by myccA.

**Note :** If the called chaincode is on the same channel, it simply adds the called chaincode read set and write set to the calling transaction.

If the called chaincode is on a different channel, only the Response is returned to the calling chaincode; any PutState calls from the called chaincode will not have any effect on the ledger; that is, the called chaincode on a different channel will not have its read set and write set applied to the transaction. Only the calling chaincode's read set and write set will be applied to the transaction. Effectively the called chaincode on a different channel is a `Query`, which does not participate in state validation checks in subsequent commit phase.